# how to handle multiple static credentials with basic auth in nodejs with koa

Tags: node.js, basic-authentication, koa

I have an api with nodejs and koa, and using koa-basic-auth package for basic authentication. 
basic auth working fine with single credential. 
I simply want to check basic auth against one or multiple static credentials. i have tried to provide multiple static credentials but not working for me.
 Any idea how to do that? want something like

```
app.use(auth({ name: 'usr1', pass: 'pass1' }, { name: 'usr2', pass: 'pass2' }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middleware you mention doesn't support that. The github pages says:

> If you require anything more specific just use the [basic-auth](https://github.com/koajs/basic-auth) module.